# get a link in jenkins to deployed artifact

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a job in jenkins that assembles zip package and deploys it to nexus. At the end of logs I get urls to this uploaded package. Next I would like to get this url somehow and pass it to next jenkins job, but I don't know how to retrieve this link from logs. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 quick options, you could parse the log with the scripting language of your choice in the next jenkins job using the [JENKINSURL]/job/[JOBNAME]/lastBuild/consoleText or if what you actually need is just the artifact you could have jenkins "Archive the artifact" and then the "Copy artifacts from another project" to pull it into the second job.